# How many channels of audio can I access via the USB interface? All 7? or muxed to 1?

Tags: microphone, azurekinect

[The help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/hardware-specification#microphone-array) doesn't tell me how many channels can I access raw via the USB interface in an application like Audacity/VLC/etc
All 7 channels independently? Muxed to 1?

Answer (score 1):

The MME and DirectSound drivers only provide access to mono and stereo audio, while WASAPI provides access to all channels. Whether the mono/stereo channels from MME and DirectSound are muxed from multiple channels or not, I'm not sure.